# Calling js function from another html file with onclick event listener

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form in one html file, and I need to call a function with onclick event listener that is in the script tag of another html file.

This is in my tracker.html file:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="highlight_date()">Track Period</button>
```

The highlight_date() function is in calendar.html file:

```
function highlight_date()
            {
                currentYear = parseInt(highlight.getYear().value);
                currentMonth = parseInt(highlight.getMonth().value);
                showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
                cell.classList.add("bg-danger");
            }
```

Is there a way to do this, because the moethod above isn't working.

Comment: In another HTML file?

Comment: you may be interested in extracting your script into a new `file.js` and making bot html contains [`<script src="file.js"></script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) in their headers

Comment: You will need to copy this code to another JS file and include in both. Why would you keep JS code in html anyway?

Comment: Copying to a shared js file won't work if the function relies on the values of elements in the 2nd html file. @user13973835 can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Each HTML file has its own JavaScript context. The way to pass data between them is with cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage.

Comment: I moved all my js code to another file and it seems to work. Thanks! Sorry I'm new to programming.